# PHP - Show database values in text boxes

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, phpmyadmin

As of right now, when I click the submit button, nothing is displayed in the textboxes. I'm submitting the `id` so that the program will know what field to find.

**EDIT**

my Submit and Input type name `id`

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
          <div class="row  col-md-4">
          <label>Code</label>
           <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control validate" id="mapo"> 
             <br>
          <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-warning" name="search" value="Search Data"></input><br>
```

Connect my php in phpmyadmin database:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'qrproject');
```

Here is my isset statement when the button is clicked then the textboxes will popup

```
 if(isset($_POST['search']))
          {
            $id = $_POST['id'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE id='$id' ";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
            {
              ?>
              <form action="" method="POST">

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $row['id'] ?>" class="form-control validate">

              <label>PIN</label>
                 <input type="text" name="pin" value="<?php $row['pin'] ?>" class="form-control validate" id="mact">
                <br>

              <label>Price</label>
              <input type="number" name="amount" value="<?php  $row['amount'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="soluong">
                <br>


              <label>Card Expiration</label>
              <input type="date" name="card_expiration" value="<?php  $row['card_expiration'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="cardex">
                <br>


              <label>Card Validity</label>
                <input type="text" name="card_validity" value="<?php  $row['card_validity'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="cardval">
                <br>

              <label>Status</label>
              <input type="text" name="status" value="<?php  $row['status'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="stats">
                <br>
 </form>
              <?php 
            }
          }
           ?>   
      </form>
```

Comment: Where is your html for the submit button? Are you sure you have return value in $query_run?

Comment: This is prone to SQL injection

Comment: @ClintonLam this is just a practice sample sir nothing serious about it

Comment: @Jesus , sir i edited the code above, yes i am sure of it everything's complete

Comment: but there's no data showing or displaying on my textboxes

Comment: If you can see textboxes with this code, you may have no value in your database or suspicious value in database to display causing improper html render.

Comment: @ClintonLam okay.. so what is the solution sir?

Comment: Make sure there are values in the databse table you are quering and double check that the database is definitely being connnect to by changing you connection code to this: `$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", 'qrproject') or die ('Couldnt find SQL Server');`

Comment: You may try `echo $row['pin'];` to check whether there is proper output. Locate the problem line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your code in the second file its not with the print command.

Change from

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $row['id'] ?>" class="form-control validate">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="form-control validate">
```

Do it for every input and everything should work.

Comment: great ! i forgot about `echo` it's been 2 years since not using pure php HAHA thanks man. but why when i submit another id number the page does not change?

Comment: @obitouchiha make sure the ID its getting rith in the query printing the $sql on screen, and then try run the code on you MySQL cli interface. Your code its not secure, try to use mysql_real_scape_string instead.